# Give Firefox extension website permissions automatically

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Im want to make my own firefox extension and i need access to a website. But every time a user installs the extension he has to click on extensions > right click the extension and click "always allow on ...". Now, how can i do this automatically? is that even possible?

Comment: Do you want the extension to automatically have permissions to a single specific site or all sites?

Comment: A single specific site.

Comment: Use the host permissions manifest key: [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/host_permissions)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: host permissions don't seem to help, at least for a temporary add-on